# Elasticsearch determinte bucket length in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl, querydsl

please help me with understanding nested bucket aggregation in elastic search. I have next query aggregation results:

```
 [...]
    {
      "key": "key1",
      "doc_count": 1166,
      "range_keys": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "happy",
            "doc_count": 1166
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "key2",
      "doc_count": 1123,
      "range_keys": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "cookies",
            "doc_count": 1122
          },
          {
            "key": "happy",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
 [...]
```

As you see, i have query results with only "happy", but i need to get **all** results **only** with "happy" and "cookies".

In order to achieve this goal i tried to use "size" argument, but this argument gave e results with size and less results query.

How i can determine "bucket" length in nested query?